# Placing local call from browser : No international authorization

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am following the [Node.js Twillio tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/04/introduction-to-twilio-client-with-node-js.html) and everything works well until the last part : calling from my browser.

My number has a +371 prefix, and I am trying to call another +371 number, so (in my mind) it should be treated as a local call, but I get the error : **13227 - Dial: No International Authorization**

My twillio number is configure to use a twiml app and this url : http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=%2B371XXXXXX while placing a voice call. The rest of the code is exactly the same as the tutorial, and I can receive calls in the browser.

Here's the request I see in the logs :

```
<Dial action="/forward?Dial=true" timeout="20" callerId="+371XXXXXXXX">+371YYYYYYYY</Dial>
```

The response to this is the warning 13227 and

```
<Response>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

So my question is : Why is this call considered international and how do I make a **local** call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

This is indeed a very good question. It sounds like your Twilio account has been setup localised in a country other than in Latvia (+371). Typically, when you attempt to buy a new Twilio number it will offer a number in your country, but perhaps this is not the case.

I opened my account in the UK, and I can easily make UK calls because they are local. I'm not sure what has happened in your case, did you create you account in a country other than Latvia?

Check your account permissions by looking at the [International Settings](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international) on your account. That should allow you to turn on calls to Latvia. Otherwise, please email your Twilio Account SID to help@twilio.com, with the above details. Twilio's support folks should be able to sort this out for your right away.